# Switch Camera while recording

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am creating app in which i am implementing the feature of record video from the camera
The recording feature work fine If i open up with back camera and record video the video will display after the recording session end and same If i open up with front camera and record video the video will display after the recording session end.

But here the issue is I am trying to implement like if user is recording video and he/she want to switch the camera while recording video without interrupting the video being recording instead extend the view Same like (SnapChat, Facebook) and then want to play the video from starting frame to ending frame.
If user didn't switch camera then the only video will be played and if user switches number of camera while recording then the all recorded session have to be played

Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class CameraaPreview extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<CameraDescription> cameras;
  const CameraaPreview(
      {super.key, required this.cameras, required this.permissionStatus});
  final bool permissionStatus;

  @override
  State<CameraaPreview> createState() => _CameraaPreviewState();
}

class _CameraaPreviewState extends State<CameraaPreview>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late CameraController _cameraController;
  late AnimationController _lottieController;
  Future<void>? _intializeFutureController;
  VideoPlayerController? _controller;
  XFile? image;
  XFile? video;
  bool _havePic = false;
  bool _haveVide = false;
  bool _isRecording = false;
  bool _flashOpne = false;
  late Timer _timer;
  bool isBackCameraOpen = true;
  int _recordedSeconds = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _initializeCameraController();
    _lottieController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 1));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _cameraController.dispose();
    _controller!.dispose();
    _lottieController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size height = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    const double navBarHeight = kBottomNavigationBarHeight;
    final avatarSize = height.width * 0.0999;
    final avataPostion = (navBarHeight - avatarSize) / 0.35;

    return _havePic
        ? _showImage(image!)
        : _haveVide
            ? _showVideo(video!)
            : FutureBuilder(
                future: _intializeFutureController,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  // if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  //   return const Center(
                  //     child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  //       color: Colors.yellow,
                  //     ),
                  //   );
                  // } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  //   return Center(
                  //     child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
                  //   );
                  // }
                  //  else
                  // if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      if (_cameraController.value.isInitialized &&
                          _cameraController != null)
                        AspectRatio(
                          aspectRatio:
                              1.09 / _cameraController.value.aspectRatio,
                          child: CameraPreview(
                            _cameraController,
                          ),
                        ),

                      //Recording Button on Camera Screen

                      Positioned(
                        bottom: avataPostion / 9,
                        left: height.width / 2.9 - avatarSize / 2,
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onLongPressStart: (_) => {
                            _lottieController.forward(),
                            _lottieController.repeat(
                                reverse: true,
                                period: const Duration(seconds: 1)),
                            _startRecording(),
                          },
                          onLongPressEnd: (_) => {
                            _stopRecording(),
                            _lottieController.stop(),
                            _lottieController.reset()
                          },
                          onTap: () => _clickPrecture(),
                          child: Lottie.asset("assets/recordingButton.json",
                              controller: _lottieController,
                              height: 155,
                              width: 155,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover),
                        ),
                      ),

                      //Camera Rotate Icon on camera Page

                      Positioned(
                        top: 65,
                        left: height.width / 1.18,
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () => isBackCameraOpen
                              ? _openFrontCam()
                              : _openBackCam(),
                          child: SvgPicture.asset(
                            "assets/camerarotate.svg",
                            color: Colors.white,
                            height: 25,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      if (_isRecording)
                        Positioned(
                          top: 20,
                          left: height.width / 2.25,
                          child: Text(
                            '$_recordedSeconds s',
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              fontSize: 24,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                    ],
                  );
                  
                },
              );
  }

  void _clickPrecture() async {
    if (_cameraController.value.isInitialized) {
      if (_flashOpne) {
        _cameraController.setFlashMode(FlashMode.always);
      } else if (!_flashOpne) {
        _cameraController.setFlashMode(FlashMode.off);
      }

      image = await _cameraController.takePicture();
      setState(() {
        _havePic = !_havePic;
      });
    }
  }

  void _startRecording() async {
    if (_cameraController.value.isInitialized) {
      if (_flashOpne) {
        _cameraController.setFlashMode(FlashMode.always);
      } else if (!_flashOpne) {
        _cameraController.setFlashMode(FlashMode.off);
      }

      _cameraController.startVideoRecording();
      _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
        setState(() {
          _recordedSeconds += 1;
        });
      });
      setState(() {
        _isRecording = true;
      });
    }
  }

  void _stopRecording() async {
    if (_cameraController.value.isRecordingVideo) {
      _timer.cancel();
      _recordedSeconds = 0;
      video = await _cameraController.stopVideoRecording();

      setState(() {
        _isRecording = false;
        _haveVide = !_haveVide;
        _controller = VideoPlayerController.file(File(video!.path))
          ..initialize()
          ..setLooping(true).then((_) {
            _controller!.play();
          });
      });
    }
  }

  void _openFrontCam() {
    _cameraController = CameraController(
        widget.cameras[1], ResolutionPreset.ultraHigh,
        imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.jpeg);

    setState(() {
      _intializeFutureController = _cameraController.initialize();
      isBackCameraOpen = !isBackCameraOpen;
    });
  }

  void _openBackCam() {
    _cameraController = CameraController(
        widget.cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.ultraHigh,
        imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.jpeg);

    setState(() {
      _intializeFutureController = _cameraController.initialize();
      isBackCameraOpen = !isBackCameraOpen;
    });
  }

  _showImage(XFile? image) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Image.file(
            File(image!.path),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 55,
          right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.18,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => setState(
              () {
                _havePic = !_havePic;
                _isRecording = false;
              },
            ),
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
              "assets/cancel.svg",
              color: Colors.white,
              height: 25,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Future<void> _initializeCameraController() async {
    _cameraController = CameraController(
      widget.cameras[0],
      ResolutionPreset.ultraHigh,
      enableAudio: true,
      imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.jpeg,
    );

    setState(() {
      _intializeFutureController = _cameraController.initialize();
    });
  }

  _showVideo(XFile? v) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: VideoPlayer(_controller!),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 55,
          right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.18,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => setState(
              () {
                _haveVide = !_haveVide;

                _controller!.pause();
              },
            ),
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
              "assets/cancel.svg",
              color: Colors.white,
              height: 25,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I am working on this and trying number of trials but didn't hit the spot
Solution to this will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Camera package supports this by default after version 0.10.4: https://pub.dev/packages/camera

See the example